# How to get data from one device and use it to trigger prompts on another device on the same network via python?

Tags: python

### Goal

Using an API, I can extract position and other data in real-time from a driving simulator to python console on the same computer. I want to then use `if-else` statements to trigger some actions on a different device. For example, if a car reaches point A in the simulator computer, then send a maths problem to the driver on a tablet (different device).
How can I connect these two devices (simulator and tablet) via python? I understand that on the tablet I can provide a GUI via an app.

#### My questions are:

1. Is the mentioned setup possible via python?
2. What will be the appropriate python package(s) for desktop app development for this use-case?
3. How can I synchronize/connect the two devices? via internet? some other way? What should I study to learn this setup?

Thank you!

*If this is not the right place to ask this question, then please direct me to where should I ask this question*.

Comment: it seems complex problem. I think It would need to create client-server using `socket` or eventually creating web server and web client and use protocol HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes. You can do this via Python. You can use any database connector with Kafka or creating an API with Flask. To connect the two device, internet might be the best way. And for your use case, internal network will do the job.

You can set this up with python, in the question, you mentioned that you will are calling an API to get some results printed on the python console. I assume that this API will keep return you results.

The first way you can do this is to also write an API which calls this API, and use `yield` to take any incoming result and then go over the if else block. And from the tablet side, you can just calling this API which would call the other API running on your computer. You can do this by setting up a rest api in python. You might want to consider [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/).

The second way is you can pass those results get from calling the first api into a database. And from your tablet code, you can actively checking the database and use those results to calculate. You can either do this by hard checking the database every second or use a Kafka Producer/Consumer.

It seems the tablet only need to know whether the car reaches points all. So you on the desktop side, you can insert timestamp and the result(true or false) into a database. And on the tablet side, you just need to keep checking the database whether contains a true result and you can use that timestamp or any other data to help you determine the result.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this advice. I will look into all the stuff you mentioned.